# JsonRest return null response

Tags: javascript, rest, browser, dojo

```
var contentJsonRestStore = new JsonRest({target: myurl});
```

Trying to implement my rest, but I keep getting a null response from my url.

1. I have access to the json content of my url from any browsers.
2. I set up my dojo project on a wamp server (so, I set it up my proxy for my dev env: localhost and my url)

Here's the error code from firefox and chrome respectively.

**Firefox (empty response):**

[image: Firefox]

**Google Chrome (f12):**

[image: Google Chrome]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you're getting Origin errors. Keep in mind that you can only send AJAX requests to the current domain (where the script is running), unless the other domain explicitly allows it (by settings `Access-Control-Allow` headers).

Did you intend to do a cross domain request?

Comment: Yes. It's working now. I set it up everywhere. Thank you very much.